# Track changes in array JS

Tags: javascript

I created a script in javascript which should track all changes between 2 arrays of strings. For ex: if element was added or removed comparing with the first array.

```js
const initial = ['test', 'color'];
const changed = ['5'];

const checkArrDiff = (initialArr, changedArr) => {
  const newElements = [];
  const removedElements = [];

  const getDiff = changedArr.reduce((acc, item, idx) => {
    if (!initialArr.includes(item)) {
      newElements.push(item)
      acc.new = newElements
    }

    if (!changedArr.includes(initialArr[idx])) {
      removedElements.push(initialArr[idx])
      acc.removed = removedElements
    }

    return acc;
  }, {})

  return getDiff;
}

console.log(checkArrDiff(initial, changed))
```

In the case above I expect the next result:

```
{
 "new": [
     "5"
  ],
 "removed": [
     "test", "color"
  ]
}
```

At the moment I get the wrong result. Who can help to fix the code?

Comment: `changedArr` has one element. `changedArr.reduce` calls the callback once with `idx` set to `0`. It's never called with `idx` set to `1`.

Comment: Also, what is the expected output if the initial and changed arrays are: `['test', 'color']` and `['test', 5]`?

Comment: What's the expected result for `const initial = ['test', 'test'];
const changed = ['test'];` and `const initial = ['test'];
const changed = ['test', 'test'];`. You probably have to overthink your approach.

Comment: The first problem can be solved with two separate filters instead of one reduce: https://jsfiddle.net/hbp8r3nk/ but that doesn't solve the second problem I described.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED ANSWER**

For example we have two arrays `arr1` and `arr2`.

```
arr1 = ["a", "b", "c"];
arr2 = ["b", "d"];
```

In above example arrays I have removed `a,c` and added `d`, but in my old code it will not give exact result what we expected, because when we remove `a` than next element `b` will move to `0` index so my old code will assume `b` as new element, but is just had changed it's index.

Here I have solved that by inserting `undefined` value at unmatched value position with `spice` function.

Now it will detect duplicated and real value. please recheck with multiple example arrays.

```js
// new example to check does it work well or not
let initial = ["a", "b", "c"];
let changed = ["b", "d"];

console.log(getDifference(initial, changed));

// main function
function getDifference(array1, array2) {
    let result = {removed:[], new:[]};

    array1.filter((item, index) => item !== array2[index] ? (result.removed.push(item) && array2.splice(index, 0, undefined)) : null);
    array2.filter((item, index) => (item !== array1[index] && item !== undefined) ? (result.new.push(item)) : null);

    return result;
}
```

**OLD ANSWER**

It will give accurate result by matching both index number and value.

```js
const initial = ['test', 'color'];
const changed = ['5'];

console.log(getDifference(initial, changed));

function getDifference(array1, array2) {
    let result = {removed:[], new:[]};

    array1.filter((item, index) => item !== array2[index] ? (result.removed.push(item)) : null);
    array2.filter((item, index) => item !== array1[index] ? (result.new.push(item)) : null);

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you iterate over the changed  array which has 1 index while you try to check 2 indexes of the initial  array.

You can simplify your logic though. I think this is what you want.

With just 2 array filter calls you can define the removed and new elements.

```js
const initial = ['test', 'color', 'both'];
const changed = ['5', 'both'];

const checkArrDiff = (initialArr, changedArr) => {
  return {
    new: changed.filter((item) => !initial.includes(item)),
    removed: initial.filter((item) => !changed.includes(item))
  }
}

console.log(checkArrDiff(initial, changed))
```

Comment: _"I created a script in javascript which should track **all changes** between 2 arrays of strings."_ Your script doesn't work for `const initial = ['test', 'test', 'test'];
const changed = ['test', 'test'];`

Comment: @jabaa The op didn't mention duplicates. If he needs to track this the occurences would need to be counted.

Comment: OP described the problem: _"track all changes"_ (duplicates are part of _"all changes"_) and posted one example. Of course, one example can't contain all possible cases. OP didn't mention upper case letters and the example doesn't contain upper case letters but it should be obvious that it should also work with upper case letters.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would use a simple loop for that and not a reduce for reasons that **jabaa** pointed out

```js
function checkArrDiff(before,after){
  var toReturn={new:[],removed:[]}
  var extras={new:[],removed:[]}
  //useless check removed by sensible suggestion by jabaa
  if(before.length<after.length){ //definitely new things
    for(let i=before.length;i<after.length;i++){
      extras.new.push(after[i])
    }
  }
  else if(after.length<before.length){ //definitely removed things
    for(let i=after.length;i<before.length;i++){
      extras.removed.push(before[i])
    }
  }
  var length=after.length>before.length?before.length:after.length //lowest length between the 2
  for(let i=0;i<length;i++){
    if(before[i]!=after[i]){
      toReturn.new.push(after[i])
      toReturn.removed.push(before[i])
    }
  }
  toReturn.new.push(...extras.new)
  toReturn.removed.push(...extras.removed)
  return toReturn
}

//example
console.log(checkArrDiff(['test', 'color'],['5']))
```

Comment: As long as there is no cleaner solution there shouldn't be a downvote for "scrappy" code.

Comment: Maybe because `before==after`. You can't compare arrays this way. This will always return false for two different arrays even if they contain the same elements: https://jsfiddle.net/t50f41da/

Comment: well, if the array is the same.. there definitely won't be any changes right.. because of that im assuming they're doing like a `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array))` to track when the array changes

Comment: `[1] == [1]` returns false because that's two different objects. The line `if(before==after){return toReturn}` doesn't make any sense because `before == after` will always be false in this code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237697/discussion-between-the-bomb-squad-and-jabaa).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution based on [@Mark Baijens solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69405494/8665500)

```js
/**
 * @param initialArr {string[]}
 * @param changedArr  {string[]}
 * @returns {{
 * newEntry: string[]
 * removedEntry: string[]
 * }}
 */
const checkArrDiff = (initialArr, changedArr) => {
    let newEntry = changedArr.filter((item) => !initialArr.includes(item));
    let removedEntry = initialArr.filter((item) => !changedArr.includes(item));

    if (!(newEntry.length && removedEntry.length)){
        const difference = Math.abs(initialArr.length - changedArr.length);

        if (initialArr.length - changedArr.length === 0){
            return {
                newEntry: [],
                removedEntry: []
            }
        } else if (initialArr.length - changedArr.length > 0){
            for (let i = 0; i < difference; i++) {
                newEntry.push(initialArr[0])
            }
        } else {
            for (let i = 0; i < difference; i++) {
                removedEntry.push(initialArr[0])
            }
        }
    }

    return {
        newEntry,
        removedEntry
    }
}


console.log(checkArrDiff(['one', 'two', 'both'], ['three', 'both']))

console.log(checkArrDiff(['both', 'both', 'both'], ['both', 'both']))

console.log(checkArrDiff(['both', 'both', 'both'], ['both', 'both', 'both', 'both']))
```